# Python - Create a column equal to the value of another column but if two consecutive values occur in the first column then make new column equal to 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column ('bet_made1') of ones and zeros where 1 represents taking a long position in a stock.

I want to create a new column that will equal the value of 'bet_made1'. However, if two consecutive 1s occur in 'bet_made1', I would like the new column to equal 0.

I would like to repeat so that a long position is followed by 4 days without another long being taken.

In other words, if I have a long position , I do not want to take another one till the 5th day after the initial buy order so that I only place a trade at a minimum of every 5 days.

Hope that makes sense. I've included a table below showing what I'm aiming for.

Cheers!

```
    bet_made1   long_pos
date        
02/01/2019  0.0 0.0
03/01/2019  0.0 0.0
04/01/2019  0.0 0.0
07/01/2019  0.0 0.0
08/01/2019  0.0 0.0
09/01/2019  0.0 0.0
10/01/2019  0.0 0.0
11/01/2019  0.0 0.0
14/01/2019  0.0 0.0
15/01/2019  0.0 0.0
16/01/2019  1.0 1.0
17/01/2019  1.0 0.0
18/01/2019  0.0 0.0
22/01/2019  1.0 0.0
23/01/2019  1.0 0.0
24/01/2019  1.0 1.0
25/01/2019  1.0 0.0
28/01/2019  1.0 0.0
29/01/2019  0.0 0.0
30/01/2019  0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Hi @zack_la, you (as the one who owns the question) can set an answer as an accepted one to show that it solved your problem, then the reputation of the one, who answered will increase. An you can up and downvote the questions and answers. Please, use this possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a more compact and tricky way, but creating a list with the new values and than add it as a new column may be a good idea:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(bet_made1=[0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1]))

long_pos = []
remains = 0
for b in df.bet_made1:
    if remains > 0:
        remains -= 1
        long_pos.append(0)
    elif b == 1:
        remains = 4
        long_pos.append(1)
    else:
        long_pos.append(0)

df['long_pos'] = long_pos
```

This gives me the result:

```
 bet_made1  long_pos   
         0         0   
         1         1   
         0         0   
         1         0   
         1         0   
         1         0   
         0         0   
         0         0   
         1         1   
         1         0   
         1         0   
         1         0   
         1         0   
         1         1
```